# Solder Type for Electrical Clamp

Tags: soldering

What type of solder should be used for attaching electrical wire to a large clamp (base wire will be screwed into clamp handle).  I am making a fractal wood burning device so current will be coming from a neon light transformer. Note specs on transformer: 10KV 10000V - Power 120V AC 50/60Hz.  I have solder for small electronic projects, but have been told such solder is not durable enough for this job.  Thanks, R.

Answer (score 3):

Use a crimp or screw connection. Don't rely on solder.

Comment: You should add why: This is a connection designed to withstand high temperature. Solder that melts at these temperatures is kind of obviously not an option here. A good screw connection, if you mean that with "base wire will be screwed into clamp handle") should suffice, though.